# Speed up processing 32 bit numbers in combinations (k from n)

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, combinations, birthday-paradox

I have a list of 128 32 bit numbers, and I want to know, is there any combination of 12 numbers, so that all numbers XORed give the 32 bit number with all bits set to 1.

So I have started with naive approach and took combinations generator like that:

```
        private static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int k, int n)
        {
            var state = new int[k];
            var stack = new Stack<int>();
            stack.Push(0);

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var index = stack.Count - 1;
                var value = stack.Pop();

                while (value < n)
                {
                    state[index++] = value++;
                    if (value < n)
                    {
                        stack.Push(value);
                    }

                    if (index == k)
                    {
                        yield return state;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and used it like that (data32 is an array of given 32bit numbers)

```
foreach (var probe in Combinations(12, 128))
{
   int p = 0;
   foreach (var index in probe)
   {
      p = p ^ data32[index];
   }
   if (p == -1)
   {
      //print out found combination
   }
}
```

Of course it takes forever to check all 23726045489546400 combinations...
So my question(s) are - am I missing something in options how to speedup the check process?
Even if I do the calculation of combinations in partitions (e.g. I could start like 8 threads each will check combination started with numbers 0..8), or speed up the XORing by storing the perviously calculated combination - it is still slow.

P.S. I'd like it to run in reasonable time - minutes, hours not years.
Adding a list of numbers as was requested in one of the comments:

1571089837
2107702069
466053875
226802789
506212087
484103496
1826565655
944897655
1370004928
748118360
1000006005
952591039
2072497930
2115635395
966264796
1229014633
827262231
1276114545
1480412665
2041893083
512565106
1737382276
1045554806
172937528
1746275907
1376570954
1122801782
2013209036
1650561071
1595622894
425898265
770953281
422056706
477352958
1295095933
1783223223
842809023
1939751129
1444043041
1560819338
1810926532
353960897
1128003064
1933682525
1979092040
1987208467
1523445101
174223141
79066913
985640026
798869234
151300097
770795939
1489060367
823126463
1240588773
490645418
832012849
188524191
1034384571
1802169877
150139833
1762370591
1425112310
2121257460
205136626
706737928
265841960
517939268
2070634717
1703052170
1536225470
1511643524
1220003866
714424500
49991283
688093717
1815765740
41049469
529293552
1432086255
1001031015
1792304327
1533146564
399287468
1520421007
153855202
1969342940
742525121
1326187406
1268489176
729430821
1785462100
1180954683
422085275
1578687761
2096405952
1267903266
2105330329
471048135
764314242
459028205
1313062337
1995689086
1786352917
2072560816
282249055
1711434199
1463257872
1497178274
472287065
246628231
1928555152
1908869676
1629894534
885445498
1710706530
1250732374
107768432
524848610
2791827620
1607140095
1820646148
774737399
1808462165
194589252
1051374116
1802033814

Comment: You can solve each bit independently. For example, if there are only three numbers that have bit 27 set, then you know that you either need one of those, or all three.

Comment: I'll say more: you **MUST** solve it bit per bit, and get groups of numbers that will solve this bit. Then, you'll compute intersections for these groups, for all bits, until you find one that uses exactly 12 numbers. It should greatly reduce the number of operations.

Comment: @Wisblade: That will be somewhat wasteful if you treat each bit completely independently.  Rather: after finding various possible solutions for the first bit, move on to the next bit and only consider solutions that don't mess up the first bit, which will be many fewer than the list of all groups which solve the second bit.

Comment: @BenVoigt The tricky part is that he needs to find a 12 numbers combination that solves the problem, not just "any" sequence that solves it... Otherwise, you're right. But if you "kill" a potential solution for, let's say bit #9, but doing this leads to a "solution" with 13 numbers, then it's not a solution. Cardinality must be checked constantly, it's more an algebra problem rather than a binary computation problem.

Comment: @Wisblade: Certainly the cardinality of the proposed set is also a way to prune entire subtrees.  But my suggestion doesn't exclude any feasible solutions, it's also a valid pruning condition.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe because I did too much algebra when I was young, but I have more confidence in it for this kind of problems: less possible algorithmic errors, and intersections and cardinality are native and very intuitive operations in algebra. I'm not very sure that complexity is in favor of one or the other approach, to be honest: both would be quite computer-intensive anyway...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Agree. Sadly, most questions are "solved" in comments (by "ancient" members most of the time) and don't even have a proper answer... Ben gave one, we speak about pertinence between the two possible approachs.

Comment: How fast shall this be? Is there a time limit? Can you share the list for testing? Where is this from? Is there anything special about the numbers, some bias/pattern, or are they random?

Comment: Thanks for comments, but I did not get how solving bit by bit could really help: if I check bit #X and find that numbers #10, #20, #30, #40 have it set, it means that odd number of them should be used. But it will not exclude all other numbers. The same is for all other bits.

Comment: There are 5.5 million times as many combinations as there are possible xor values, so there's almost certainly a combination with the desired xor value. I found one easily, with a little Python script within a minute. Which makes me wonder even more about what I asked already: Where is this from? What is the point? It just seems strange.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized your sample numbers aren't just random. Most bits are set in about half of all numbers, but bit 31 is set in just a single number (so that number must be in any solution). And bit 27 is set in 91 of the 128 numbers, deviating from 64 by 27, far more than the next-larger deviation (bit 12 appears 51 times, deviating from 64 by only 13). Why is that? Where did these numbers come from?

Comment: @KellyBundy the OP never said that the 128 numbers are random.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah I know, they just looked random to me in first inspections. I'm just pointing out that they aren't and asking why. Maybe knowing how they came to be can give us more insights and opportunities to exploit something. That's why I'm asking about that.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias "OP never said" ... "OP has no obligation" ... I never said they said that or have an obligation. I don't know you you're saying such things. I'm merely trying to help, and I'm asking for more information so I can help better.

Comment: I have marked answer by @KellyBundy as it solves immediate probelm of finding combination, and it is a good idea to spit input data.

However, I am still interested if there any clever way to do such things, e.g. with bit elimination. I have found other related question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150103/xor-number-combinations
but what I could understand, it will allow to find a minimum set of numbers which will be minimum reuired to represent all bits. But it will not help to find arbitary set of numbers with given length which xored to 0XFFFFFFFF

Comment: This problem might be a variant of the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: I have found similar probelm, called Generalised birthday problem:
“given k lists of n-bit values, find some way to choose one element from each list so that the resulting k values xor to zero.”, also k-xor probelm.
https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2002/24420288/24420288.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C#, I did something in Python, maybe interesting anyway. Takes about 0.8 seconds to find a solution for your sample set:

```py
solution = {422056706, 2791827620, 506212087, 1571089837, 827262231, 1650561071, 1595622894, 512565106, 205136626, 944897655, 966264796, 477352958}
len(solution) = 12
solution.issubset(nums) = True
hex(xor(solution)) = '0xffffffff'
```

There are 128C12 combinations, that's 5.5 million times as many as the 2<sup>32</sup> possible XOR values. So I tried being optimistic and only tried a subset of the possible combinations. I split the 128 numbers into two blocks of 28 and 100 numbers and try combinations with six numbers from each of the two blocks. I put all possible XORs of the first block into a hash set `A`, then go through all XORs of the second block to find one whose bitwise inversion is in that set. Then I reconstruct the individual numbers.

This way I cover (28C6)<sup>2</sup> × (100C6)<sup>2</sup> = 4.5e14 combinations, still over 100000 times as many as there are possible XOR values. So probably still a very good chance to find a valid combination.

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZXRbps3DIXv/RS6i10EAUVRFBWgF32OYRuc1l6NJbZhO0OHos@efXTTbd36O4iFXxR5eHiOfPzz8vGwb3E8vbxsT4ensrtsTpfD4fFcdk/Hw@lS3h@eHnb79WV32J8X15Dt8/79dyGnzYfn95uvm4fj5rS@HE7f9j6xXJ/z69fFYv/8dC5vy@PufFk@rY/L3f5yW25qH1ViRhtFq4whKj6LuUtvMXpR9RAdMUsX16oSo1hYlWbTSw31np9eplnMkavahojY1CjDotZoLqVKPi5CZNc@STCLylCbYzaheO3eepvsu6vbyPSqU6p5ayV0qKu2ysvhtVo3KlmIVXUHJ4sgUbTSq4KoCudHGy2UA9S33jvx@VZnGx14dZjr6FNGgvY@ZHYrlbIhdYSStTaVKY1T3qU7FIGgzw6WmFZMO@RBQhl5uGlU3imRg0o2Rus6O5X4z/6kExI3GuGvhFFoCqs62xydypOmzMQa/VDIJdhqJIgqkzpNS7LE@zkSaYg0ccsEzUOhluWYxIrB@ozByMyJ7drMoKVm28kkBQh0n7WVGd1NRJ1XET6J5URtzIw69DYSfIILjsDHYCIN6hkOzZn0CJotxi6jqVFoUoBnnInoanVSGNW0sJ4coqrqwEtksIwCkxpXxNMzFGZpr9WUBp/OqFgKmFIeBXoZbmoMUtAjjDB4pARJkcISbzYq2QcEdeWLQo2xdbsua3VjOJYio8sWTlK4V@si9DEn6FvxYELtmijwChqBVuRv0/AJw0VLvSt46TdcU/8iNArRLEHIJJtmlw3K8YqVNsFNP5FDEcN3ct0PEgmpps9mOinEoJgo/aNP9cqh1C8dMgbIKigZpUTuj@iImVSoIlLHDvqUIuTjY7CHw7ZXyJnMGg1rpkICpPZ0PwhZ436uBIzbEDUcMQnTYrhEA/5BgiyYEzdGnRgBQUSaKjy1DlHp6qtwSYr5kESSMvBsY06pIW/ME2WynCONNnDSwFFMDStz@2hcrQ5PuLYmUqqgS08ru06815EoykLTNtPKNWfeuUoQi4yGkJgtNxpkYRomDWmechqTawulEenYGdlz6fAK5Tr6Ru2W90YijfQOOk1TGU7XRJIaHIZ@riIW3Fnt5u58fNxdlqvVarH4sNnmnbv8Y/14Xt0vCs9pc3k@7V8v62VeyLflur1YvONS/pzh69Uv8mn7@tyX9fVg2eYdXnb7734LlnmZ/3Sv8fNt8dWXxSKjHn4cpXF/jfoKZLcl2/3b8u7ut80lgSwfVq9b@TycNuvfF4vz4fE5UyS0N@vb8uaBGscTPxnL7c3nf@1@uVn98/5xs19@21v9d/Pbxt3ufH5@OFM80f0v7OPm0xXV33leI15e/gI)):

```py
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor as xor_

nums = list(map(int, '1571089837 2107702069 466053875 226802789 506212087 484103496 1826565655 944897655 1370004928 748118360 1000006005 952591039 2072497930 2115635395 966264796 1229014633 827262231 1276114545 1480412665 2041893083 512565106 1737382276 1045554806 172937528 1746275907 1376570954 1122801782 2013209036 1650561071 1595622894 425898265 770953281 422056706 477352958 1295095933 1783223223 842809023 1939751129 1444043041 1560819338 1810926532 353960897 1128003064 1933682525 1979092040 1987208467 1523445101 174223141 79066913 985640026 798869234 151300097 770795939 1489060367 823126463 1240588773 490645418 832012849 188524191 1034384571 1802169877 150139833 1762370591 1425112310 2121257460 205136626 706737928 265841960 517939268 2070634717 1703052170 1536225470 1511643524 1220003866 714424500 49991283 688093717 1815765740 41049469 529293552 1432086255 1001031015 1792304327 1533146564 399287468 1520421007 153855202 1969342940 742525121 1326187406 1268489176 729430821 1785462100 1180954683 422085275 1578687761 2096405952 1267903266 2105330329 471048135 764314242 459028205 1313062337 1995689086 1786352917 2072560816 282249055 1711434199 1463257872 1497178274 472287065 246628231 1928555152 1908869676 1629894534 885445498 1710706530 1250732374 107768432 524848610 2791827620 1607140095 1820646148 774737399 1808462165 194589252 1051374116 1802033814'.split()))

def xor(vals):
    return reduce(xor_, vals)

A = {xor(a)^0xffffffff: a
     for a in combinations(nums[:28], 6)}

for b in combinations(nums[28:], 6):
    if a := A.get(xor(b)):
        break

solution = {*a, *b}

print(f'{solution = }')
print(f'{len(solution) = }')
print(f'{solution.issubset(nums) = }')
print(f'{hex(xor(solution)) = }')
```

Comment: How much time does it take to report that there is no solution for an input of 128 even numbers? To get such an input, you could zero the final 1 bit of all odd numbers in the OP's question: `n = ~(~n | 1)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I estimate that the current code (just rewrote it again) would take about 20 minutes to go through such a set. Note, though, that it's really an optimistic approach, betting on many solutions existing so that it has a good chance to find one at all and find it early. With the current split into 28 and 100 values, I check about 1.9% of the possible combinations of 12 values.

Comment: Could you try it out? My gut feeling is that it should take much more than 20 minutes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias My laptop is old and slow and tio.run has a one minute time limit. But the 20 minutes is not a wild guess. What I did was run the above code but with `nums[28:80]` instead of `nums[28:]` and replaced `break` with `pass` so it goes through all. That took about 20 seconds. The full range has about [60 times](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28100+choose+6%29+%2F+%2852+choose+6%29) more combinations, and they'd get processed at the same speed.

Comment: So the *"0.8 seconds to find a solution"* has been measured on your laptop or on tio.run?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias On tio.run. You can see it there at the bottom of the page in the "Debug" section. Tried it on my laptop now, took 1.9 seconds.

Comment: If you were able to provide an actual measurement for the time needed to report the result for 128 even numbers on any machine, instead of a theoretical estimation, you would earn my upvote. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Did it on a GCE instance, took 9 minutes 35 seconds.

Comment: Interesting approach, split not only combinations in two C6 portions, but also to divide input data. What is not clear for me: for the case with 28C6 vs 100C6 - only combinations of first 28 and last 100 are compared.
What if correct combination belongs to the 12 from the last 100?

Comment: @DmitryT Then it won't be found. I thought about some variations that check more/all of the possible combinations of 12, but don't see something really good yet. Like I said it still checks over 100000 times as many as there are possible XOR values, so probably still a very good chance to find a valid combination. The coverage would increase from the mentioned 1.9% to over 10% if you split at 42 instead of at 28, btw, just would take more memory and time to build `A`. Like I said, this is something optimistic, since it is so very likely that there are many solutions.

Comment: @DmitryT I just ran it again but instead of stopping at the first solution I counted them. It found 12451 solutions (and took ~11 minutes). Splitting at 42 instead of at 28 found 80046 solutions (and took ~5 minutes). Splitting at 64 found 240991 solutions (and took ~2 minutes, but took 11.4 GB memory).

Comment: @DmitryT Hmm, just had an epiphany. I can simply try all possible splits, from 6 to 122. That would cover all possibilities. It would be more expensive, but it's not as bad as it might seem at first. If splitting at let's say 80, I wouldn't build the set for the 80, which would take ~46 GB memory. I'd instead build the set for the other 48. So no memory issue. And if splitting at let's say 6, I don't need to check all 122C6 combinations of the other 122. Think of the split index as the index of the seventh element in the overall combination. So splitting at 6 needs only checking 121C5.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your numbers into buckets based on the position of the first `1` bit.

To set the first bit to `1`, you will have to use an odd number of the items in the corresponding bucket....

As you recurse, try to maintain an invariant that the number of leading `1` bits is increasing and then select the bucket that will change the next `0` to a `1`, this will greatly reduce the number of combinations that you have to try.

Comment: Hello Ben, I like you idea to not use bruteforce check, but I could not understand how this arrangement should work. 
I have found something similar in 5 years old question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150103/xor-number-combinations
but from what I could see, it will eliminate all numbers which are not unique (could be combined as XOR from other numbers), and it is not what I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution, which could work for my particular task.
As main issue to straitforward approach I see a number of 2E16 combinations.
But, if I want to check if combination of 12 elements equal to 0xFFFFFFFF, I could check if 2 different combinations of 6 elements with opposit values exists.
That will reduce number of combinations to "just" 5E9, which is achievable.
On first attempt I think to store all combinations and then find opposites in the big list. But, in .NET I could not find quick way of storing more then Int32.MaxValue elements.

Taking in account idea with bits from comments and answer, I decided to store at first only xor sums with leftmost bit set to 1, and then by definition I need to check only sums with leftmost bit set to 0 => reducing storage by 2.
In the end it appears that many collisions could appear, so there are many combinations with the same xor sum.

Current version which could find such combinations, need to be compiled in x64 mode and use  (any impovements welcomed):

```
    static uint print32(int[] comb, uint[] data)
    {
        uint p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < comb.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", comb[i]);
            p = p ^ data[comb[i]];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" #[{0:X}]", p);
        return p;
    }

    static uint[] data32;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 128;
        int k = 6;
        uint p = 0;
        uint inv = 0;
        long t = 0;

        //load n numbers from a file
        init(n);

        var lookup1x = new Dictionary<uint, List<byte>>();
        var lookup0x = new Dictionary<uint, List<byte>>();

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        //do not use IEnumerable generator, use function directly to reuse xor value
        var hash = new uint[k];
        var comb = new int[k];
        var stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(0);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var index = stack.Count - 1;
            var value = stack.Pop();

            if (index == 0)
            {
                p = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Start {0} sequence, combinations found: {1}",value,t);
            }
            else
            {
                //restore previous xor value
                p = hash[index - 1];
            }

            while (value < n)
            {
                //xor and store
                p = p ^ data32[value];
                hash[index] = p;
                //remember current state (combination)
                comb[index++] = value++;

                if (value < n)
                {
                    stack.Push(value);
                }

                //combination filled to end
                if (index == k)
                {
                    //if xor have MSB set, put it to lookup table 1x
                    if ((p & 0x8000000) == 0x8000000)
                    {
                        lookup1x[p] = comb.Select(i => (byte)i).ToList();
                        inv = p ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        if (lookup0x.ContainsKey(inv))
                        {
                            var full = lookup0x[inv].Union(lookup1x[p]).OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();
                            if (full.Length == 12)
                            {
                                print32(full, data32);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //otherwise put it to lookup table 2, but skip all combinations which are started with 0 
                        if (comb[0] != 0)
                        {
                            lookup0x[p] = comb.Select(i => (byte)i).ToList();
                            inv = p ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
                            if (lookup1x.ContainsKey(inv))
                            {
                                var full = lookup0x[p].Union(lookup1x[inv]).OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();
                                if (full.Length == 12)
                                {
                                    print32(full, data32);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    t++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Check was done in {0} ms ", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //end
    }
```

Comment: How fast is it? And what do you mean with it *"**could** work for my particular task"*? Do you not know because it's still running or why?

Comment: @KellyBundy, first it collects all combinations started with position 1, and it is the longest chunk of combinations. Only after that it will find opposites to compare.
From the start sequence started with 1: combinations processed: 254231775, time: 343668 ms
Thats on system with i7@2.6GHz, but as long as it is single threaded it boosts to 4Ghz. And allocates 16GB of data.

Comment: So for the specific set of numbers that you have posted in the question, what is the answer? Does a combination of 12 numbers that is XORed to 0xFFFFFFFF exist, or not?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, and there is a lot of such combinations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I also just constructed one. Not hard to find, as there are about 5.5 million times as many combinations as there are possible xor values, so unless there's some bias/pattern in the data, there are probably around 5.5 million such combinations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Which btw makes this a rather strange question. Might even be challenging to construct a set of 128 numbers that *doesn't* have a solution :-) (ah, no, we can simply use 128 even numbers)

Comment: Dmitry I think that the condition of the XORed combination being 0xFFFFFFFF is a trap. It doesn't make the problem any easier. It could be any other number, and the problem would be just as difficult.

Comment: Regarding the problem of storing 5,423,611,200 XOR sums in a dictionary, my suggestion is to reduce the length of the precalculated combinations from 6 to 5. Then you'll have to store only 264,566,400 XOR sums, which is feasible. Then scan all length-7 combinations (94,525,795,200 combinations), and search for their complement in the dictionary. It might take hours or days, but not years.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I see now that condition (all bits are set) which is 0xFFFFFFFF do not add any good to current solution of brute-force check. In this sense, probably yes, it could be any number. But I think it should be some clever way of eliminating the numbers, as in other answer - unfortunately I could not understend it.

Comment: @DmitryT maybe there is a clever solution, or maybe not. I am inclined to bet on the "maybe not" right now. The problem is probably just as difficult as it seems to be (brute force is required).